# SQL Server Arabic question mark

Tags: sql-server

I have Arabic data in the table but it is displayed as a question mark:

[image]

How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Use `nvarchar`, not `varchar`. [nchar and nvarchar (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: what is the datatype of "Clientname" column?

Comment: Most likely this column `Clientname` is of `varchar` data type, not `nvarchar` like the other column (`Reason`) where everything seems fine.

Comment: Is your column `NVARCHAR`? Are your queries using the correct types, and prefixing their literals with `N`? Is the process that's supposed to insert the values Unicode-aware? Try `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), clientname)` -- if this returns a long string of `3F` (question mark), your data is already corrupted by things that didn't understand Unicode, and you'll have to reinsert it.

Comment: thank you for your answer ,the column data type is varchar, Can I get the old data?

Comment: No. The data was converted to `VARCHAR` (that is, a lot of question marks) upon storage. If you need the Unicode data, you'll have to get it from somewhere outside this table.

Comment: thanks alot for you

Answer (score 2):

Change the type of `clientname` nvarchar and the collation to `Arabic_100_CI_AI`, then in the insert query you have to add N before inserting the value, like in this example:

```
insert into table_name (...,clientname,..) values (...,N'محمد علي',....);
```